# SQL UPDATE select w/ multiple to a PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, sql-update

I'm aware of the SQL injection issues in this code. I am however focusing on just trying to get form to update the mySQL server. I have two select boxes that are populated. I can transfer the equipment back and forth between the two. However when I go to update It does not work. PLEASE HELP ME!

HERE is FORM:

```
$connection = mysql_connect('#', '#', '#'); 
mysql_select_db('#');

$techequipment = "SELECT serial, type_id FROM tbl_assets WHERE user_id = {$_GET ['TechID']} AND date_installed IS NULL AND date_returned IS NULL AND metro_date_returned IS NULL ORDER BY type_id, serial";
$techresult = mysql_query($techequipment);

$jobequipment = "SELECT serial, type_id FROM tbl_assets WHERE account_number = {$_GET ['JobNum']} ORDER BY type_id, serial";
$jobresult = mysql_query($jobequipment);

$link = array($_GET ['JobNum'])
?>
<title>Assign Equipment</title>
<table align="center">
<form action="assigned_equipment.php?<? echo http_build_query($link)?>" method="POST">
<tr>    
<td><center><b><?php echo "Tech #"; echo $_GET ['TechID']; echo " Assigned Equipment"; ?></b></center></td> 
<td></td>   
<td><center><b><?php echo "Job #"; echo $_GET ['JobNum']; echo " Assigned Equipment"; ?></b></center></td>  
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<select  name="tech[]" size=20 multiple   id="list1"  STYLE="width: 350px">
<?php $i=0; while($row = mysql_fetch_array($techresult)) { ?>
<option value="<?=$row["serial"];?>"> <?=$row["type_id"]." - ".$row["serial"];?></option>
<?php $i++; } ?> </select>  
</td>

<td>
<center><input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Transfer >>"/></center>
<center><input type="button" id="btnRemove" value="<< Transfer"/></center>
</td>

<td>
<select  name="job[]" size=20 multiple   id="list2"  STYLE="width: 350px">
<?php $i=0; while($row = mysql_fetch_array($jobresult)) { ?>
<option value="<?=$row["serial"];?>"> <?=$row["type_id"]." - ".$row["serial"];?></option>
<?php $i++; } ?> </select>  
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2">
</td>

<td>
<center><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/></center>
</form>
</td>   

</tr>   
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<center>Multi Select: Press & hold [CTRL] while clicking on the items.</center>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<center><a href="jobs.php">EXIT</a></center>
</td>
</tr>

</table>



<script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function () {

//TAKE EQUIPMENT FROM TECH AND PUT IT IN JOB BOX            
            $('#btnAdd').click(
                function (e) {
                    $('#list1 > option:selected').appendTo('#list2');
                    e.preventDefault();
                });


//TAKE EQUIPMENT FROM JOB AND PUT IT IN TECH BOX
                $('#btnRemove').click(
                function (e) {
                    $('#list2 > option:selected').appendTo('#list1');
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
        });
</script>
```

Here is my assigned_equipment.php file:

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect('#', '#', '#')
    or die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('#');

$equipmentquery="UPDATE tbl_assets SET date_installed = curdate(), account_number = {$_GET['0']} WHERE serial = $_POST['job']";

$techquery="UPDATE tbl_assets SET date_installed = curdate(), account_number = {$_GET ['0']} WHERE serial = $_POST['tech']";

?>
```

Comment: are you shure that "0" is a valid variable name?

Comment: `WHERE user_id = {$_GET ['TechID']}  ` this no secure becase, i write in TechD=12' + union select and blablabla -- ... and you get `where user_id=12' union select 1,1,1,1,,1 -- coment ` and I get access to database.

Comment: please try to send the jobnum via post,too. use a input type=hidden.

Comment: And mysql_ module is deprecated in new version php

Comment: and your name for the techlist is not "techlist" it is "tech"! Maybe you sould do a print_r of your post vars before to be shure what your variables look like.

Comment: print_r ($_POST) says Array ( [job] => Array ( [0] => gi4416ncd876 [1] => GI4521NA3391 [2] => M40719GD6274 [3] => PAEH01734539 ) )

Comment: VAR_DUMP ($_POST) says array(1) { ["job"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(12) "gi4416ncd876" [1]=> string(12) "GI4521NA3391" [2]=> string(12) "M40719GD6274" [3]=> string(12) "PAEH01734539" } }

Comment: ok so your job is there. but it is an array! and what about your jobnum?

Comment: Job number is in the address bar I pull it with $_GET

Comment: mysite.com/dev/assigned_equipment.php?0=113852

Comment: Yes you try to pull it with $_GET. But your variable name is "0" and I am not shure that this is a valid name. Do a `print_r($_GET);` or a `echo $_GET['0'];` to be shure that you get what you expect.

Comment: print_r ($_GET) says Array ( [0] => 113852 )

Comment: Can you explain in words what the objective of your `UPDATE` statements is?

Comment: I want to take the list of serial numbers and update the tbl_assets table. Look up the record by the serial number and add today's date to the date_installed column and the job number to the account_number.

Comment: I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, you are right it seems to be the case that "0" is a valid variable name to submit via $_GET or $_POST. So this is not a problem.

But your problem is that `$_POST['job']` is an array.

You try to do this:

```
$equipmentquery = ""
. "UPDATE tbl_assets "
. "SET date_installed = curdate(), "
. "account_number = {$_GET['0']} "
. "WHERE serial = $_POST['job']";
```

While `$_POST['job']` is an array you cannot do it like this!

Please try the following:

```
$jobnum = (int)$_GET['0'];
$job_arr = $_POST['job'];

if(($jobnum > 0) && is_array($job_arr) && (count($job_arr) > 0)) {

    $equipmentquery = ""
        . "UPDATE tbl_assets "
        . "SET date_installed = curdate(), "
        . "account_number = ".$jobnum." "
        . "WHERE "
        . 'serial IN ("'.implode('","',$job_arr).'") ';
}
```

Ok what happens here?

I suspect that your serial holds the values posted in job array.
So you want to update each row where your serial matches the posted values in your array.

In case of your $_POST: `Array ( [job] => Array ( [0] => gi4416ncd876 [1] => GI4521NA3391 [2] => M40719GD6274 [3] => PAEH01734539 ) )` and your $_GET: `Array ( [0] => 113852 )`  it will result in the following query:

```
UPDATE tbl_assets 
SET date_installed = curdate(),
account_number = 113852 
WHERE serial IN ("gi4416ncd876","GI4521NA3391",
"M40719GD6274","PAEH01734539")
```

Ok now you have a working query.
Not it is time to execute it!!!

therefore you need to:

```
$result = mysql_query ( $equipmentquery );
```

this is the important line, you are missing!

Finally your code may look like this:

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect('#', '#', '#')
    or die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('#');

$jobnum = (int)$_GET['0'];
$job_arr = $_POST['job'];
$tech_arr = $_POST['tech'];

if(($jobnum > 0) && is_array($job_arr) && (count($job_arr) > 0)) {

    $equipmentquery = ""
        . "UPDATE tbl_assets "
        . "SET date_installed = curdate(), "
        . "account_number = ".$jobnum." "
        . "WHERE "
        . 'serial IN ("'.implode('","',$job_arr).'") ';

    $result1 = mysql_query ( $equipmentquery );

}
if(($jobnum > 0) && is_array($tech_arr) && (count($tech_arr) > 0)) {

    $techquery = ""
        . "UPDATE tbl_assets "
        . "SET date_installed = curdate(), "
        . "account_number = ".$jobnum." "
        . "WHERE "
        . 'serial IN ("'.implode('","',$job_arr).'") ';

    $result2 = mysql_query ( $techquery );

}
```

**When this works, you should directly switch to mysqli or pdo!
mysql_ functions are deprecated and not present any more in the latest php version! You should really care about sql injection! So use prepared statements to clean up your input data!!! There are various tutorials out there!!! DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN A LIVE ENVIRONMENT**

Comment: So do you have some matching serial values in your db? If not, what should be updated?

Comment: Yes the serial numbers are pulled from the same table.

Comment: Just a simple question: Are you executing the query after storing it in variable `$equipmentquery`? I cannot find a execution line in your posted code!

Comment: I just did a echo $_POST('job') and it comes up blank?

Comment: what I posted is everything.

Comment: What i got so far and it's not updating... 
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect('#', '#', '#')
 or die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('#');
$result = mysql_query ( $equipmentquery );


$jobnum = (int)$_GET['0'];
$job_arr = $_POST['job'];

if(($jobnum > 0) && is_array($job_arr) && (count($job_arr) > 0)) {

    $equipmentquery = ""
        . "UPDATE tbl_assets "
        . "SET date_installed = curdate(), "
        . "account_number = ".$jobnum." "
        . "WHERE "
        . 'serial IN ("'.implode('","',$job_arr).'") ';
}

?>

Comment: please read my edit. You need to send your query to database via `mysql_query(...)`. Otherwise nothing will ever happen.

Comment: I do the connection, i added the $result = mysql_query ($equipmentquery); and then I added the update portion... am i missing something here?